# Is it possible to use a derived class virtual method from a base class non-virtual method?

Tags: c++, oop, gcc, polymorphism, c++14

I have multiple derived classes which extends the same Base class. They have the same properties, with the exception of a single method that might have different arguments and body. How can I have a std::unique_ptr and call methods for the derived classes?

Here is what I know so far:

1. A function template can not be `virtual`;
2. A pure virtual function can not be overriden with a different signature;
3. A function pointer would require to know the argument list of all possible derived functions

Here is what I'm currently leaning torwards (without success):

**Base class:**

```
class IBase
{
  /** ... **/
  template <class T, typename ...Args>
  MyCustomType perform(T &obj, Args ... args)
  {
    std::bind(obj->run, args);
  }

  virtual MyCustomType run(...) = 0;
};
```

**Derived class:**

```
class Derived : IBase
{
  /** ... **/
  virtual MyCustomType run(MyType1 a, MyType2 b, bool c) override
  {
    /* code */
  }
};
```

I wanna be able to use my pointer to the base class, call `basePtr->perform(a, b, c)` and the method from subclass `Derived` to be executed. Does it make any sense?

Comment: `Dervied` doesn't actually derive from anything (probably just a typo?). You probably have to manually write all overloads.

Comment: "A pure virtual function can not be overloaded;" - sure it can.

Comment: "*A pure virtual function can not be overloaded*" - not true. Functions can always be overloaded, whether they are pure or not. Maybe you meant overridden? Pure functions must always be overridden, by definition.  What you can't do, though, is declare a virtual/pure function one way, and then try to override it in a descendant using different parameters, like your example shows. That will not work.  An overridden function must match the same signature as the function it is overriding. And in fact, the `override` keyword was added in C++11 to enforce that.

Comment: @Remy "Pure functions can (and must) always be overridden" - nitpicking a bit here; a pure function *can* have an implementation, so you don't actually *have* to override it to give it an implementation always.

Comment: @JesperJuhl "*a pure function can have an implementation*" - Yes, but it must also be overridden in a descendant. That is the whole point of declaring a `virtual` method as pure. A non-pure `virtual` method does not have to be overridden, but a pure `virtual` method must be. But that override can invoke the default implementation, if it wants to.

Comment: Why is the `Derived::run` method marked as `virtual`? Shouldn't it be not marked as virtual so that it overrides `IBase::run`?

Comment: `virtual` dispatch seems like the wrong tool for the job here.  Given only an `IBase*`, how would you call `run` if every derived class's `run` method has a different signature?

Comment: How would you call the function?

Comment: @HenriqueSabino specifying `virtual` in a derived class is optional when overridding a base method.  Once a method is marked as `virtual`, it is always virtual in all subsequent descendants.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks! I'm kinda new to C++ and found that weird, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: You might be able to use [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to do this, but I don't have time at the moment to be sure or go into details.

Comment: @MarkRansom CRTP is static dispatch, but `virtual` is for dynamic dispatch, so that doens't help either

Comment: The crux of this is that template functions can't be virtual, fundamentally. It _literally doesn't make sense_, when you think about it. This is not an arbitrary limitation. There's no weird hacks you can use to sidestep this.  Find a different way to solve whatever it is you're trying to do. Since you never said what that was, we can't answer this question.

Comment: Put differently: if different derived classes have "a single method that might have different arguments", then those are different functions, period, by every measure.  Each class has a different function. Therefore there's no single function in the interface to even attempt to call.  You'd have to cast the interface to the derived type, then call that type's unique method.

Comment: @MooingDuck suppose I have 'Maestro' class that only have a pointer to a `Player` (base) class. The method `play` for the `Piano : Player` and for the `Violin : Player` needs different inputs. I wanna call different play implementations from the Maestro class without having multiple signatures defined in the Player class.

Comment: No, you want to call one method on a `Piano` that takes Piano inputs, and a completely unrelated method on `Violin` that takes a Violin input, and the unrelated methods happen to have the same name.

Comment: One could make a `ReadyPlayer` class that contains a `Piano` and also `PianoMusic` input, and a  `ReadyPlayer` that contains a `Violin` and a `ViolinMusic` input objects, store those in a list, and this `ReadyPlayer` has a `play` method with _no_ inputs.  That's possible.

Answer (score 0):

> with the exception of a single method that might have different arguments and body

That's not a thing C++ lets you do directly. C++ is a statically typed language; the caller and the callee of a function must statically agree on what is being passed and what is being returned. Period.

Your only option for doing what you're attempting is to employ static type erasure like `std::any` or similar techniques (like hiding data behind a `void*`, but that's highly dangerous). That is, you can pass "parameters" to a function via a `tuple` of values stored in an `any`. And the return value can be an `any` as well.

However, the sending code would have to know *exactly* what the receiving code expects and vice-versa; you can't unpack an `any` without knowing exactly what you expect to be there. So the interface is generic, but the receiver and sender still have to have some agreement on what exactly is going on.

And you definitely do not want the receiving function trying a bunch of different casts over and over again to figure out which set of parameters was provided and therefore which function body to call.

Broadly speaking, you should avoid such interfaces whenever possible, due to the high propensity for errors and mistakes.

Comment: He can build a list of functions, each of which is a Derived/Method pair bound together, then execute the list of functions.

Answer (score -3):

I think I got a possible solution to the initial idea, using [Variadic Function Templates](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variadic-function-templates-c/).

```
class IBase
{
  template <typename ... Args>
  MyType run(Args... as)
  {
    MyType result;
    return result;
  }
};
```

Then I can overload this method in `Derived`:

```
class Derived : IBase
{
  /** ... **/
  MyType run(const MyOtherType &X, const int &a);
};
```

Can anyone think of a problem with this solution?

Comment: That won't work, as `Derived::run` will not override `IBase::run`. They're unrelated methods with the same name. So there's no way to call `Derived::run` though an `IBase` pointer.